# Is it possible to put an Activity in a TabHost which is in a Fragment already?

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity` which hosts a `Fragment` which hosts a `TabHost` which need to set its `tabs` with `Activities`. Is that actually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Activities cannot hold other activities within themselves.

For this, you use fragments.

However, you can use fragments withing fragments, even though I find it very confusing .